# Full width bootstrap dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I´m trying to make a Bootstrap menu similar to the menu in this page..https://makr.com/

This is what I have come up with and I´m pretty much stuck at the moment.

How I can make the dropdown text appear beneath each dropdown button like it is on the https://makr.com/

index.html

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
   <!-- Header -->
   <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" 
         data-toggle="collapse" 
         data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      Bootstrap 3 Skeleton
      </a>
   </div>
   <!-- Navbar Links -->
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li class="dropdown full-width">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" 
               data-toggle="dropdown">
            Full Width <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
               <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Long
                  </a>
               </li>
               <li class="divider"></li>
               <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
               <li class="divider"></li>
               <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li class="dropdown full-width">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" 
               data-toggle="dropdown">
            Full Width <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
               <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Long
                  </a>
               </li>
               <li class="divider"></li>
               <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
               <li class="divider"></li>
               <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li class="dropdown full-width">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" 
               data-toggle="dropdown">
            Full Width <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
               <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Long
                  </a>
               </li>
               <li class="divider"></li>
               <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
               <li class="divider"></li>
               <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

custom.css

```
.full-width.dropdown {
    position: static; 
}
.full-width.dropdown > .dropdown-menu {
    position: static;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.full-width.dropdown > .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    white-space: normal; 
}
.fill-width.dropdown {
     position: static;
 }
.fill-width.dropdown > .dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    left: auto;
}
.fill-width.dropdown > .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    white-space: normal; 
}
```

javascript

```
$('.dropdown').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn();
    }, 
    function() {
        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut();
    }
);
$('.dropdown-menu').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).stop(true, true);
    },
    function() {
        $(this).stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut();
    }
);
```

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle?

Comment: Please check the fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/redmoLbx/

Comment: They're not making the dropdown element itself full width. They're extending the height of the parent element to contain the dropdown element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/a92com1a/4/

To make this kind of effect, `.dropdown-menu` needs to be static, also `dropdown-toggle` needs to have a fixed width

```
.dropdown-menu{
  position: static;
}

.dropdown.full-width {
  width : 120px;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I know...I tried this before, but in this solution the text inside the dropdown is always aligned to the left no matter what. I want the text in each dropdown button appear beneath it´s button when hovered as in [link](https://makr.com/)